# How to migrate gitlab from 7.8 version to 10.4?

Tags: migration, gitlab

I have GitLab 7.8.4. And now I need to migrate on new 10.4 version on another server. I'll tried to copy `/git-data/repositories` into new server but this is not enough. 
Can some one describe the steps for this migration? Is that posible for new version?

UPD
I can't restore with `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore`

```
gitlab@git-repo:~$ sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:restore BACKUP=1518174912
Unpacking backup ... done
GitLab version mismatch:
  Your current GitLab version (10.4.1) differs from the GitLab version in the backup!
  Please switch to the following version and try again:
  version: 7.8.4


Hint: git checkout v7.8.4
```

UPD2
My new server with ubuntu 16.04 
GitLab version (10.4.1) Omnibus 
PostgreSQL

Comment: I guess it is pretty obvious but https://about.gitlab.com/update/ could be enough. Also it is recommended to upgrade to some versions in between, and avoid such big jumps between version numbers.